# AMCL husky problems

Tags: navigation, clearpath, amcl-demo.launch, husky, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use amcl to drive a robot around my school. It failed to load saved maps, but seemed to accept when I told it to use the /map topic. The problem I am having now though is that nothing is happening. I have tried using the amcl_demo.launch file, as well as launching amcl_husky.launch and move_base_husky.launch separately. In rviz I press the 2D pose estimate button to set the pose, but there is no effect. In the terminal it states that it is setting the post on frame /map and gives coordinates, but rviz does not show the collection of arrows that the wiki says it should. As well, when I press the 2D Nav Goal button and select the goal, the terminal states that it is setting the goal in frame /map and gives the position and orientation coordinates but again nothing shows up in rviz and the robot does not move. I am not sure what is going on and would appreciate any help you can give. I am following the turtlebot_navigation tutorial as it says to do on the husky navigation page on the wiki, except that I am using the /map topic rather than a saved map as I stated above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60134/amcl-husky-problems/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-18**:
@icehawk101 you can just accept the answer and it will get filtered as closed, you don't need to close it as well.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-04-18**:
Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I got it working. Turns out that in the move_base_husky.launch file the velocity commands are mapped from cmd_vel to plan_cmd_vel. I changed that to /husky/cmd_vel and the robot started moving.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1